Data Driven UI - event handling
Currently in our web app, we have forms which define model and view in JSON (in-house library) on the client side. Example:

And there is a component for each form, which has

event handling logics like, clear value of Bar if Foo's value is XYZ. There logics can be complex too.
complex validation logics (simple validations are part of JSON itself)

Now, we want to make UI free of all this event handling and complex validation logic to free UI from domain specific code.
Does it make sense to move validation and event handling logic in JSON (using json-logic-js maybe) and get everything including model/view from the backend API?
Will it be a good design?

Is that logic only for the UI? Not for backend? If so, then you want to introduce a new language (because that's what this JSON thingy is) and push the responsibility for managing it onto backend, with no benefit for the backend. Sorry, that's very bad. Unless backend can use it as well, in which case it is only very complicated with unknown security risks. I suppose this is acceptable if some well known common language is used instead, on both sides. Like JS itself.
